# How do I get rid of the grey bar in UINavigationController (iOS app)

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I'm using this code to open up a page in my iOS app when a user clicks a button, but I get a grey bar at the top of the page when the user does so. How can I get rid of this?

```
- (IBAction) colours:(id)sender   { 
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:colourPickerView];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
}
```

Comment: In the view did load of colorpickerview you can hide navigation bar of navigation controller.

Comment: didn't work in viewDidLoad, needed to add in viewWillAppear - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be referring to the navigation bar created by the navigation controller.

To hide it just use this.

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Yes, I needed to add that in the viewWillAppear method of the controller that holds the UINavigationController. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the status bar containing the clock and batter indicator, you can do:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];`

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 4, use the property `isNavigationBarHidden`.

`navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true`