# YTPlayerView adding a grey bar automatically. cant get rid of it

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, youtube-api, ytplayerview

[Here is the screen where the grey area is shown between navigation bar and video player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adQHQ.png) .

I read this one as well.
[Grey bar appearing under Navigation bar after segues Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769987/grey-bar-appearing-under-navigation-bar-after-segues-swift)

But didn't understood the solution as it didn't worked for me.
Need help to get this portion off.
Anyone faced this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try hiding the navigation bar created by the navigation controller if that what you mean. Use `[navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];` as stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11350115/5995040). Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that. If I hide navigation bar then that grey portion looks like a navigation bar.

Comment: @RaselKhan Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55647807/4982152